# How do I disable field name in logrus while logging to file

Tags: logging, go

I am using logrus in golang to log to file. Right now, logrus is logging to file with field name.

ie

`time="26-03-2017 03:37:58" level=error msg="Not fatal. An error. Won't stop execution"`

How do I remove the field names so that the log entry becomes

`ERRO 26-03-2017 03:37:58 Not fatal. An error. Won't stop execution`

like how it behaves in case of stderr?

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to get what you requested:

```
package main

import (
    log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
    "fmt"
)

type PlainFormatter struct {
    TimestampFormat string
    LevelDesc []string
}

func (f *PlainFormatter) Format(entry *log.Entry) ([]byte, error) {
    timestamp := fmt.Sprintf(entry.Time.Format(f.TimestampFormat))
    return []byte(fmt.Sprintf("%s %s %s\n", f.LevelDesc[entry.Level], timestamp, entry.Message)), nil
}

func main() {
    plainFormatter := new(PlainFormatter)
    plainFormatter.TimestampFormat = "2006-01-02 15:04:05"
    plainFormatter.LevelDesc = []string{"PANC", "FATL", "ERRO", "WARN", "INFO", "DEBG"}
    log.SetFormatter(plainFormatter)
    log.Errorln("Not fatal. An error. Won't stop execution")
    log.Infoln("Just some info")
}
```

- Create the PlainFormatter struct (with timestamp format and level fields)
- Create a Format function/method (where your struct is the receiver)
- Set logrus to use your custom formatter

Output:

```
ERRO 2017-07-01 18:22:21 Not fatal. An error. Won't stop execution
INFO 2017-07-01 18:22:21 Just some info
```

In my book [Learn Functional Programming in Go](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/learning-functional-programming-go) book you can see a more practical example of how you can manipulate your application logger in *Adding Functionality with Decoration* chapter.

Comment: Thanks for this example. Is it possible to use it with `logrus.WithFields`? I tried but didn't sucess.

Comment: Also, I don't get it how the "Format" function works if you never call it. I added one more field to `PLainFormatter` but it gave me an error. How may I add one more field to the log?

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a custom formatter that emits only the fields you want to see.

There is an example in the [logrus readme](https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus#formatters):

```golang
type MyJSONFormatter struct {
}

log.SetFormatter(new(MyJSONFormatter))

func (f *MyJSONFormatter) Format(entry *Entry) ([]byte, error) {
  // Note this doesn't include Time, Level and Message which are available on
  // the Entry. Consult `godoc` on information about those fields or read the
  // source of the official loggers.
  serialized, err := json.Marshal(entry.Data)
    if err != nil {
      return nil, fmt.Errorf("Failed to marshal fields to JSON, %v", err)
    }
  return append(serialized, '\n'), nil
}
```